# NodeJS Deployment Https

Tags: node.js, https, deployment

I have web application with Angular 8 on frontend,and NodeJS on backend.
I deploy that app on DigitalOcean droplet and everything works fine,but when I bought domain and run app on HTTPS frontend can't recive information.

[ERROR IN CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clG9G.jpg)

Comment: You will need an SSL certificate set up in order to use HTTPS.  I also recommend running your NodeJS app behind Nginx and stopping SSL there.  

Digital Ocean has some good tutorials on this:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I understand logic,i would still run node js on http,but I must add valid ssl to nginx ?

Comment: Yes, correct.  It's much simpler to keep your nodejs app HTTP (for testing and other reasons) and not expose the port it's on to the world and proxy it behind Nginx (which is open to the world).

Nginx will also allow you to redirect port 80 to port 443 (HTTP > HTTPS) and is very performant as a web server.